# Returning the size of the largest clique in a graph

Tags: c++

This function is to return the size of the largest clique in a graph. When I run this code, I am running out of space at runtime. Also, it is insanely slow, so any speed tips would be appreciated.

```
int cliqueSize(graph &g, std::vector<VertexID> nodes, std::vector<EdgeID> edges)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<VertexID> > previous_cliques;

    // start with all the singular nodes...
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<VertexID> tmp;
        tmp.push_back(nodes[i]);
        previous_cliques.push_back(tmp);
    }

    for (unsigned clique_size = 1; clique_size < nodes.size(); clique_size++)
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<VertexID> > new_cliques;
        // go through all the nodes to try to add to the clique.
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
        {
            // try to add node i to clique j.
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < previous_cliques.size(); j++)
            {
                // make sure node j is not already in the clique.
                if (std::find(previous_cliques[j].begin(), previous_cliques[j].end(), nodes[i]) == previous_cliques[j].end()) 
                {
                    std::vector<VertexID> potential_clique(previous_cliques[j]);
                    potential_clique.push_back(nodes[i]);

                    // isClique has no issues, just checks if the given graph is a clique...   
                    if (isClique(g, potential_clique, edges))
                    {
                        new_cliques.push_back(potential_clique);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // no new cliques? 
        if (new_cliques.size() == 0) { return clique_size; }
        else { previous_cliques = new_cliques; }
    }
    return nodes.size();
}
```

Comment: IDK if you still care about this question, but if you do: you do know that max-clique is NP problem? So it is "normal" that you have problems solving it. Ofc you can improve perf, but fundamentally there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 4):

- First of all, start passing things by const reference more.  You're passing both `nodes` and `edges` by value, which will make a copy.
- Instead of looping through the containers by index, you should use iterators.
- Pushing `tmp` into `previous_cliques` will make a copy.

The following may be faster:

```
std::vector<VertexID> tmp(1);
for (...) {
    tmp[0] = nodes[i];
    previous_cliques.push_back(tmp);
}
```

(If you're worried about scope, just wrap it in braces.)

- Checking for emptiness with `size()` may be less efficient than with `empty()`; unlikely in the case of a `vector`, though (I think `size()` must be O(1)).
- You're not showing us `isClique`, so it's hard to comment on that.  Make sure you're passing be const reference there.  Also consider not copying `previous_cliques` until you know you want to push it into `new_cliques` and instead handling `nodes[i]` as a special case (may be faster, may be slower).
- If you're using C++11, the `emplace` functions are your friend.

Comment: Thanks for these tips.  Just a question.. I just tried the code snippet you provided to speed up copying the tmp() vectors into previous_cliques, and that doesn't compile, since nodes[i] is a VertexID, and tmp is a vector of VertexIDs.   Is that compiler dependent?  I'm using VS2010

Comment: @notebook: Nope, that's a typo on my part, good catch. :)

Comment: Saving the value of `end()` in a variable would make no difference speed (even if the container did not cash (or the difference is so small you could not measure it)). All the containers in modern version of the library cache a copy for re-use and the end() call returns a const reference to this cached copy. If you don't modify the value it will be just as fast and if you do modify the container it is safer. Thus prefer to always call end().

Comment: @LokiAstari: I have seen measurable differences in speed between caching the manually and calling `end`.  Granted, these were in more complicated cases (the container was a class member, and there was some recursion involved).  Seeing as the vectors aren't passed out of the function this may not matter, but it may still be worth trying.  (By the way, the return type of `end` is `iterator`, not `iterator const&`.  Not that it matters, as it is probably inlined.)

Comment: @AntonGolov: The return type is `iterator or const_iterator for const a` so badly worded on my part. But I would love to see an example of a situation where you can actually measure the difference in cost between calling end() every iteration and caching it once at the beginning in a situation where the actual container is not altered in the loop (ie remains const).

Comment: @LokiAstari: If in the following code, the definition of `dummy` is placed in a different source file, the difference in runtime will be very significant (about 50% worse).  If it is in the same source file, it seems like the optimiser handles it just fine.  http://ideone.com/hDBw0  Granted, this is not very relevant in this case.

Comment: @AntonGolov: I tried putting `dummy()` in both the same and different compilation units. Seems like this shows that calling end() each time is faster. (Assuming you compile with -O3)

Comment: @LokiAstari: Ah, -O3 versus -O2 seems to make a difference in this case.  I'm still not sure why I can't reproduce the problems I had earlier, and I'll see if I can construct a more appropriate example eventually, but I doubt it'll apply in this case so I'll remove the advice.

Answer (score 2):

#### Comments on algorithm

Your current algorithm is O(N^3) This can definitely be turned into **O(N^2)**

From reading the code you want to build a list of all sub-graphs that exist in your graph.

I think you are doing t wrong and building several of the subsets repeatedly.

There is a simple technique for this.
Think of each node in the graph as represented by a bit in a very large integer where the integer has one bit for every node in the graph. Node 0 is bit 0 and Node 5 is bit 5 etc. Thus the full graph is represented by the integer with all the bits set to one.

Any sub set of the graph is then represented by an integer with some bits off and some bits on. Thus you can generate all the different sub-sets of the graph by looping through all bit patterns in the integer and this can be done simply by starting at 1 and incrementing the integer until all the bits have been set (Each increment represents a new set).

Assuming you have more nodes than will fit into a normal integer you should probably use the boost::dynamic_bitset(If you have 64 or fewer nodes you can use a normal integer (assuming you have 64 bit integer type)).

```
/*
 * This function adds 1 to the bitset.
 *
 * Since the bitset does not natively support addition we do it manually. 
 * If XOR a bit with 1 leaves it as one then we did not overflow so we can break out
 * otherwise the bit is zero meaning it was previously one which means we have a bit 
 * overflow which must be added 1 to the next bit etc.
 */
void increment(boost::dynamic_bitset<>& bitset)
{
    for(int loop = 0;loop < bitset.count(); ++loop)
    {
        if ((bitset[loop] ^= 0x1) == 0x1)
        {    break;
        }
    }
}

int cliqueSize(graph &g, std::vector<VertexID> const& nodes, std::vector<EdgeID> const& edges)
{
    static boost::dynamic_bitset   empty;
    empty.resize(nodes.size());

    int                       cliquesCount = 0;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<>   set(nodes.size());
    set[0] = 1;

    while(set != empty()) // break when all bits are zero.
    {
        // Build the next potential clique
        // Every bit that is a 1 in set means that that nodes is in the clique.
        std::vector<VertexID>  cliques;
        for(int loop = 0;loop < nodes.size(); ++loop)
        {
            if (set[loop])
            {
                cliques.push_back(nodes[loop]);
            }
        }

        // If this is a clique increment the count.
        if (isClique(g, cliques, edges))
        {
             ++cliquesCount;
        }

        // Increment the set bits by 1 each loop.
        // This effectively iterates through all different bit patterns.
        increment(set)
    }
    return cliquesCount;
}
```

#### Comment on code

You should prefer to pass parameters by const reference if you can.

```
int cliqueSize(graph &g, std::vector<VertexID> const& nodes, std::vector<EdgeID> const& edges)
                                              ^^^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^^

std::vector<std::vector<VertexID> > previous_cliques;
```

The following can be simplified a bit:

```
    std::vector<VertexID> tmp;
    tmp.push_back(nodes[i]);
    previous_cliques.push_back(tmp);

    // Easier to read like this:
    previous_cliques.push_back(std::vector<VertexID>(1, nodes[i]));

    // If you have C++11 (emplace_back uses move semantics to put the object in the vector)
    previous_cliques.emplace_back(std::vector<VertexID>(1, nodes[i]));
```

Prefer to use pre-increment for loop variables.

```
for (unsigned clique_size = 1; clique_size < nodes.size(); ++clique_size)
                                                           ^^
```

Though it makes no difference for POD types. It gets you in the habit of always using the pre-increment version. This will help you out when the type is not an integer type as generally speaking the pre-increment is more efficient. Also if you change the type from integer (to say iterator) it will automatically be the most efficient version.

You are returning the wrong value:

```
return nodes.size();

// I think you mean:
return new_cliques.size();
```

Comment: On that last point. new_cliques is out of scope. nodes.size() is the correct fall-through answer for one all-encompassing clique.

Comment: @PaulMartel: You seem to have missed the point entirely. If node.size() is the answer then there seems little point in the function as it can be reduced to a single line. `int cliqueSize(graph &g, std::vector<VertexID> nodes, std::vector<EdgeID> edges) {return nodes.size();}`

Comment: Too funny, 'cause I do remember feeling like I was entirely missing the point. I thought "that function could be reduced to that one line" and half-considered making that my answer -- but then I remembered that the function had multiple return statements, and the moment quickly passed.

Comment: @PaulMartel: And yet you are still missing the point.

Comment: In your proposed algorithm, isn't the while loop O(2^n)?  That would make the algorithm O(n*2^n)?  O(n*2^n) quickly overtakes O(n^3).  Although it is cleaner, easier to read, and I suspect better on memory.

Answer (score 2):

#### Initial conditions

If each element of edges always represents a clique of two elements of nodes, start by returning 0 if nodes is empty else 1 if edges is empty, else begin looping with clique_size = 2 and each element of previous_cliques initialized to each edge's VertexID pair rather than to each node's single VertexID.

#### Vector flattening

Since each round N produces some variable number of N-ary cliques, it may be faster,
though a bit trickier, to build `previous_cliques` as a flat vector of VertexID where every Nth element represents the start of a new clique.

A variant on this idea would further capitalize on the flatness of the `previous_cliques`/`new_cliques` vectors by using a "double buffering" scheme
that limited itself to a single pair of VertexID vectors, possibly allowed to grow as
needed and retained for the duration of the function. The vectors would take turns
in the roles of `previous_cliques`/`new_cliques` and each have an explicit `elements_used` high water index potentially different from its actual initialized size. The high water would get reset when it took on the role of `new_cliques` and trailing elements from past rounds simply ignored.

All of this is somewhat second-guessing the memory manager and some of the benefits could be achieved more abstractly by packaging it as actual new/deletes with an alternative recycling-savvy Allocator strategy, if that's your idea of time well-spent.

#### Clique-first iteration

With or without this optimization, if the node loop is nested within the clique loop instead of vice versa, each clique in `previous_cliques` can get copied *once* into a temp vector, with its new last element simply *assigned into* by each candidate VertexID in turn (vs. using `push_back`). Then the grown vector, *if* it is a clique, can be copied into new_cliques (flattened or not). This will reap SOME of the benefits of "only copy on success" as suggested in the excellent answer by @Anton while still allowing passing a simple vector (`const &`) to `isClique`.

#### Optimizing for mathematical properties of cliques

Assuming that the clique semantics are independent of the order in which their VertexIDs are added, i.e. there is no useful distinction between clique `{B,A}` and clique `{A,B}` or between the results of `{A,B} + C` and `{A,C} + B`, culling of equivalent cliques can boost efficiency.
An ordering of VertexIDs -- even an arbitrary ordering that's stable for the duration of the function -- can be used to only count "canonical form" cliques that list their elements in order. With that restriction in place, many uninteresting duplicate cases can be eliminated just by skipping in the inner loop any VertextIDs that sort at or before the previous clique's last VertexID.

Another optimization is possible because/assuming N-ary cliques are composed of N overlapping (N-1)-ary cliques.  At a minimum, this means that when the total number of N-ary cliques is N or fewer, N can be returned as the largest clique size.

#### And there may be more, if you can stand it

N-1 of those N overlapping (N-1)-ary cliques will reference each of the VertexIDs in the N-ary clique. So, as a possible trade-off, track the number of times each VertexID was listed in any N-ary clique -- like in a VertexID-keyed map, preferably a sorted one for use in the range-skipping inner loop mentioned above. This allows any VertexID that was listed fewer than N times to be removed from the set of VertexIDs considered for adding in later rounds.  Any N-ary clique that contained it would also be not worth building on. Either of these might be especially tricky and/or expensive to track, though.